# Using purrr and modelr to make predictions from dose-response models (drm)

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, drc, modelr

I have a data set that looks, in abbreviate form, like this:

```
library(tidyverse)    
dat_s<-tibble(
      type=c(rep("A", 9), rep("B", 8), rep("C", 10)),
      ref=c("ref3", "ref3", "ref1",  "ref2", "ref2", "ref1", "ref2", "ref2", "ref2", "ref2", 
            "ref1", "ref2", "ref2", "ref3", "ref2", "ref3", "ref1", "ref3", 
            "ref2", "ref3", "ref1", "ref1", "ref3", "ref1", "ref1", "ref2", "ref2"),
      info=as.character(sample(100, 27)),
      liv=c(3.0e-05, 2.9e-07, 2.2e-07, 2.7e-07, 2.6e-06, 4.8e-07, 1.4e-05, 2.6e-06, 7.7e-06, 2.2e-06, 
            1.5e-07, 1.6e-07, 1.8e-06, 6.1e-08, 4.9e-06, 4.9e-06, 1.8e-06, 1.5e-07,
            4.3e-08, 1.8e-06, 1.0e-07, 1.6e-07, 9.7e-07, 1.0e-06, 6.4e-07, 1.2e-07, 5.7e-06),
      prod=c(0.00, 2, 3, 4.80, 2.10, 5.10, 0.00, 0.13, 2.00, 0.13, 0.00, 4.10, 4.60, 2.10, 0.26, 0.00, 
             4.60, 0.00, 4.60, 2.10, 4.80, 0.00, 0.00, 1.80, 3.60, 4.10, 0.00)
    )%>%
  mutate(livp1=liv+1)
```

I want to calculate dose response relationships for each combination of `type` and `ref`, make predictions to plot a curve, and calculate residuals. The `info` column is to reflect that I have additional columns in this data frame which I need to preserve, but are not important in the dose-response analysis.

I start by creating the models using a function and a nested data frame:

```
dr_s<-function(df){drc::drm(data=df, prod~log(livp1), fct=drc::LL.3())}

dat_mods<-
  dat_s%>%
  group_by(type, ref)%>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(dr_mod=map(data, dr_s))
```

Which works to create the models and put them in the data frame. To use `add_predictions` with models of the type `drm`, the input has to be a `data.frame` (rather than a `tibble`). When I try to add predictions for each `livp1` variable (according to the comments below):

```
dat_mods%>%
```

mutate(mod_preds=map2(data, dr_mod, ~add_predictions(data=as.data.frame(.x), model=.y))))

I get a `non-numeric argument to binary operator` error message. This code works fine when the `info` column is not `character` class. However, I need to retain this information with the predicted data, and would like to avoid pulling it from the data frame if possible.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was pretty silly, the `predict` method for models of class `drm` doesn't work on objects of class `tibble`. So you have to convert `.x` to `data.frame`.

```
dat_s%>%
  group_by(type, ref)%>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(dr_mod=map(data, dr_s),
         mod_preds=map2(data, dr_mod, 
                        ~modelr::add_predictions(data = as.data.frame(.x[,"livp1"]),
                                                 model = .y)))
## A tibble: 9 x 5
## Groups:   type, ref [9]
#  type  ref   data             dr_mod mod_preds       
#  <chr> <chr> <list>           <list> <list>          
#1 A     ref3  <tibble [2 × 4]> <drc>  <df[,2] [2 × 2]>
#2 A     ref1  <tibble [2 × 4]> <drc>  <df[,2] [2 × 2]>
#3 A     ref2  <tibble [5 × 4]> <drc>  <df[,2] [5 × 2]>
#4 B     ref2  <tibble [4 × 4]> <drc>  <df[,2] [4 × 2]>
#5 B     ref1  <tibble [2 × 4]> <drc>  <df[,2] [2 × 2]>
#6 B     ref3  <tibble [2 × 4]> <drc>  <df[,2] [2 × 2]>
#7 C     ref3  <tibble [3 × 4]> <drc>  <df[,2] [3 × 2]>
#8 C     ref2  <tibble [3 × 4]> <drc>  <df[,2] [3 × 2]>
#9 C     ref1  <tibble [4 × 4]> <drc>  <df[,2] [4 × 2]>
```

Comment: That makes sense! However, when I unnest to look at the results, they're not what I would expect as prediction output -- it looks like the model applied every column as possible input. 
 `dat_mods<-
dat_s%>% group_by(type, ref)%>% nest() %>% mutate(dr_mod=map(data, dr_s))%>% mutate(mod_preds=map2(data, dr_mod, ~modelr::add_predictions(data - .x, model = .y,  type = "data.frame")))%>% unnest(mod_preds)`  
Could it be that I have to specify something else as `.x` and `.y`?

Comment: That works perfectly for the data I gave! However, I apparently made example data not perfectly reflective of my original data -- `info` should technically be several character columns. I didn't think the difference would matter at the time (and I don't think the number of columns does), but apparently calling `as.data.frame(.x)` affects the data type for `livp1`, as I'm getting the good ol' `non-numeric argument to binary operator` error. I'm editing my original question, and would be very grateful if you could take another look?

Comment: The issue with that is where to subset. If I do it within `add_predictions`, (e.g., `data=as.data.frame(.x)$livp1`) it makes it a vector, which `predict` in any form doesn't like. Unless we can find a more elegant solution, I think I'm going to have to just break apart and re-combine the tables. Sorry again for goofing up on the original question code!

Comment: Take a look at my edit, if you subset `.x` with the `[` operator, it returns a tibble, which can then be converted to a data.frame. There are annoying subtle differences between `[` and `$`.

Comment: TADA! I also just found out it also works if you `unnest()` before predicting: `mutate(dr_mod=map(data, dr_s))%>%  unnest(data)%>% mutate(mod_preds=map2(livp1, dr_mod, ~add_predictions(data=as.data.frame(.x), model=.y)))`, but I'm all for saving lines of code :)

Comment: Glad it worked. I don't think there's anything to beat yourself up about. I honestly got lucky finding the issue. The only reason I figured it out was because I tried to use `predict` manually on the data.